# Flex 3 What Does this Error Mean, in General?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I'm running into this error, but I don't understand what it means. Has anyone else run into a similar error?

```
Error: Unable to load ''.
    at mx.controls::SWFLoader/loadContent()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\SWFLoader.as:1617]
    at mx.controls::SWFLoader/load()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\SWFLoader.as:1380]
    at mx.controls::SWFLoader/commitProperties()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\SWFLoader.as:1167]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:5807]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:539]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:659]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher2()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8628]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8568]
```

What could cause this error to be thrown? This error is shown as soon as I run the project. I got this error and a white screen.

I'm trying to get some javascript to work with Flex 3. Could it be related? Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Run the code in the debugger, so you can find out what line in your code is causing it.  (Flex Builder, if you have it, `fdb` if not.)  Then post the code surrounding that line if that doesn't immediately clue you into the problem.  You mention JS, but I wouldn't try to debug this in the context of your existing web app.  Hack your Flex app if necessary so it will run as a standalone Flex app to isolate concerns.

Comment: When does this error occur?  +1 on testing it in debug mode to figure out which line is causing the error.  If you don't have Flash Builder or FDT, I thought the Flex SDK had a command line debugger.

Comment: Are you setting `source` property of any SWFLoader of any of its subclasses (Image) to an empty string? My guess is that you're assigning the result of some e4x query (that accidentally turns out to be an empty string) to the source property.

Answer (score 0):

The error "unable to load ''" means that a file without a file path or URL defined as the source attribute is being referenced in the swfloader MXML element

**References**

- [Apache Flex: swfloader](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html)